# Where the Distributed ledger will store in hyperledger composer and fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Thanks in advance,
                 I have one doubt that , where the ledger will store exactly. Whether in local machine or in cloud.

Comment: see https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#recap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run blockchain platform on your machine, it will be stored in your local machine. If you run it on cloud, it will be stored on cloud.

About concept of ledger refer to [Here from fabric document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/ledger/ledger.html)

Fabric stores 2 types of data, world state(final or current key/value set), and blockchain(transaction history).

world state data is stored into embedded Level DB, or external one such as CouchDB. Transaction history will be stored into your peer node(/var/hyperledger/production). So, the data location is up to your system configuration.